# How to force values in column be unique in SDV multi table HMASynthesizer?

Tags: python, sdv

I got this table:

|  | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Region_0 |
| 1 | 1 | Region_1 |
| 2 | 2 | Region_2 |
| 3 | 3 | Region_3 |
| 4 | 4 | Region_4 |
| 5 | 5 | Region_5 |
| 6 | 6 | Region_6 |
| 7 | 7 | Region_7 |
| 8 | 8 | Region_8 |
| 9 | 9 | Region_9 |
| 10 | 10 | Region_10 |
| 11 | 11 | Region_11 |
| 12 | 12 | Region_12 |
| 13 | 13 | Region_13 |
| 14 | 14 | Region_14 |
| 15 | 15 | Region_15 |
| 16 | 16 | Region_16 |
| 17 | 17 | Region_17 |
| 18 | 18 | Region_18 |
| 19 | 19 | Region_19 |

I trying to make new data.
Metadata for this table:

```
database_metadata.update_column(
    table_name='region',
    column_name='id',
    sdtype='id',
    regex_format='[0-9]{2}'
)

database_metadata.set_primary_key(
    table_name='region',
    column_name='id'
)

database_metadata.add_relationship(
    parent_table_name='region',
    child_table_name='users',
    parent_primary_key='id',
    child_foreign_key='region_id'
)


'region': {'primary_key': 'id',
   'columns': {'id': {'sdtype': 'id', 'regex_format': '[0-9]{2}'},
    'name': {'sdtype': 'categorical'}}}
```

I need to make region's names unique.
How to put this logic in model?

P.S. The constraint class 'Unique' is not currently supported for multi-table synthesizers.

Answer (score 1):

SDV will ensure that primary keys and alternate keys are always unique in the generated synthetic data. Since column `'id'` is already listed as a primary key, you can then add column `'name'` as an alternate key.

From [the docs](https://docs.sdv.dev/sdv/multi-table-data/data-preparation/multi-table-metadata-api#add_alternate_keys):

> Similar to primary keys, alternate keys are also unique in your table. However, other tables do not reference alternate keys.

```py
metadata.add_alternate_keys(
    table_name='region',
    column_names=['name']
)
```